# Is a realistic chemistry system viable for video game design (restrictions apply)?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I assume this might be an unusual question, and I'd like to first make a note as to why I'm asking here, on Chemistry Stack Exchange and not somewhere more relevant to video games. This is because we'd like to get an answer from people with knowledge in the field of chemistry since we want to approach the issue from the direction of verisimilitude.

We have a simulation/adventure game with the capacity for complex item manipulation. This means that we can already handle things like containers for substances, laboratory equipment, item combinations (including combinations which require multiple inputs and specific tools), etc. These systems were developed for other reasons than specifically a chemistry system, but the idea of building one cropped up.

The issue is that we are not informed enough to properly assess the feasibility of building such a system, especially under the limitations described below. And if such a system was possible, we are unsure where to start looking up information about it.

The restrictions that we're working under are:

1. We make a game where the player character is non-violent and thus have no interest in including things such as explosives or poisons. Instead, we are interested in puzzle/environmental problem solving and possibly some medicine;
2. We'd be simplifying things to some degree, partly for quality-of-life reasons and partly so that people can't follow the in-game processes in real life. I will additionally note we work on a horror game for adults;
3. If it were to exist, it would need to be an actual system rather than including specific recipes for crafting without multiple uses for the components;

We'd appreciate any opinions on the matter, as well as any more specific suggestions for material we should study.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it.

There is a sophisticated system to learn about genetics through a game: https://concord.org/teaching-genetics/dragons/

There is a game to try to figure out protein folding: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foldit

The chemistry domain that might fit is organic synthesis, with rule-based or AI based prediction engines available: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2095809922005665

All of these have development costs that are probably beyond your budget.

There are also pandemic-borne simulations of teaching labs, but those are script based and boring.

So I doubt it’s possible to make something fun within the chemistry domain on a small budget, but it would be great if I’m wrong.

You could also look I to board games for inspiration, e.g. covalence, https://www.teachersource.com/product/covalence-molecule-building-game.

Comment: Thank you for your response. In broad terms, I absolutely agree with you.

However, my post was specifically related to everyday chemistry, and as such, what you are referring to has little to do with what we were considering doing. We don't want to gamify anything like organic chemistry or genetic. We're looking to add to already existing systems, in a game that is fundamentally not focused on chemistry.

So for example, environmental problem solving means we're looking for the system to be useful when the character traverses the environment or interacts with objects within it.

Comment: You want "multiple uses for the components". You could have different miniaturized analytical instruments (like the Star Trek tricorder) to help solve environmental problems. There could be one for organic volatiles, one for elemental analysis, and one for water-soluble organic substances. And there could bet a set of tools and a set of reagents to sample to environment and get samples into a state ready for analysis. Otherwise, all I can think of for everyday chemistry are different solvents (cleaning, dissolving evidence), and ?pool chemistry? (measure pH, chlorine, and add acid, base, ...)

Comment: The "pool chemistry" idea is actually very interesting. Thank you. I'll look into that.